# How to check if any items in an array (php) is in a table (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a random character generator, but how can I check if an result already exist in the database?
E.g., if I want 5000 results, and 1 result is equal to an result in the database, it must create a new result in the for-loop.

```html
$previous = array();

for ($i=1; $i<=$quantity; $i++){
                       
    $unique_found = false;
    while(!$unique_found){
        $a = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
        $b = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
        $c = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);
        $d = substr(str_shuffle("1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 4);

        $code = "$a-$b-$c-$d";

        if(!in_array($code,$previous)){
            $unique_found = true;
            $previous[] = $code;
            echo .$code .'<br>';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing in above code??

Comment: You can check into database but what if your data is too much ? I like to suggest Timestamp(); of php which will provide you unique key every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate the $previous array with results in the database already.

```
$previous = array();
$sql = "SELECT `code` FROM `table`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $previous[] = $row['code'];
}

for ($i=1; $i<=$aantal; $i++){
    // ....
```